# Slicing a string in python and converting it to an integer

Tags: python, string, split

I've been trying to sort registration numbers. The registration number is of the format 18[a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]

so I've tried this function

```
def cutt(n):
    n=int(n[5:9])
```

Is there something I need to return? It shows after using the function that it has a none datatype

Thank you

Comment: is n a string?.

Comment: If you don't `return` something, python returns `None`.

Comment: yes it is a string

Comment: I cannot see how this should return something sorted.

Answer (score 2):

You should do like this:

```
def cutt(n):
    return int(n[5:9])
```

and in your code:

```
old_n = '18abc1234'
new_n = cutt(old_n)
```

the your `new_n` will be `1234`.

Comment: if I try to use it with a list element then it gives me int object is not subscriptable

Comment: It says that your list items are Integer. you should pass string.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code

```
def cutt(n):
    n=int(n[5:9])
    return n
```

**Checking**

```
val=cutt("18xyz3456")
print(val)
```

**Output**

```
3456
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Using it with a list element gives that int is not subscriptable